# How would I go about repeating this simulation 1000 times to get a list output from which I can take the mean?

Tags: r, simulation, gamma-distribution

I'm trying to simulate 1000 trials of the following situation to get a mean output of cost. In addition to what's included below, each simulation would need to stop if the totalTime >= 6. I struggle a lot with for loops and simulations so I would appreciate it if anyone can give me any tips for creating this simulation. Thanks!

```
cost <- 0
devices <- 0
totalTime <- 0
unitCost <- 100

failureTime <- rgamma(1, shape=2, scale=.5)
if (failureTime>1) {
  cost <- cost + unitCost
  totalTime <- totalTime + failureTime
} else {
  cost <- cost
  totalTime <- totalTime + failureTime
}
```

Comment: Your notion of "stop" seems to suggest that in addition to repeating this full-simulation 1000 times, you want each simulation to loop until a condition is met. If you have a basic 1-full-simulation working somewhere, then you can use `replicate(1000, { your_code_here; })`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replicate` like below

```
replicate(1000, {
    cost <- 0
    totalTime <- 0
    unitCost <- 100
    while (totalTime < 6) {
        failureTime <- rgamma(1, shape = 2, scale = .5)
        cost <- cost + unitCost * (failureTime > 1)
        totalTime <- totalTime + failureTime
    }
    cost
})
```

Note that you need a `while` loop to judge if `totalTime` reaches `6`, and `cost` (or `totalTime` as well) is output once the `while` loop is terminated.

---

If you want `data.frame` output, you can try the code below

```
out <- do.call(
    rbind,
    replicate(1000,
        {
            cost <- 0
            totalTime <- 0
            unitCost <- 100
            while (totalTime < 6) {
                failureTime <- rgamma(1, shape = 2, scale = .5)
                cost <- cost + unitCost * (failureTime > 1)
                totalTime <- totalTime + failureTime
            }
            data.frame(cost = cost, totalTime = totalTime)
        },
        simplify = FALSE
    )
)
```

which gives

```
> head(out)
  cost totalTime
1  200  6.117942
2  200  6.010357
3  400  6.255933
4  400  6.082638
5  300  7.170587
6  200  7.046343
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to first have a full-running simulation work 1 time. To do that and honor your *"stop if the totalTime >= 6"*, you need something like a `while` loop.

I suggest writing a function that does this one thing very well and returns the two variables you want (cost and total time). Once you have that, it's trivial to replicate it.

```r
simfunc <- function(shape = 2, scale = 0.5, unitCost = 100) {
  cost <- 0
  totalTime <- 0
  while (totalTime < 6) {
    failureTime <- rgamma(1, shape = shape, scale = scale)
    if (failureTime > 1) {
      cost <- cost + unitCost
    }
    totalTime <- totalTime + failureTime
  }
  c(cost = cost, totalTime = totalTime)
}

set.seed(42)
simfunc()
#      cost totalTime 
#    200.00      6.86 
simfunc()
#      cost totalTime 
#    400.00      6.79 
simfunc()
#      cost totalTime 
#    300.00      6.95
```

From here, we can replicate it easily:

```r
set.seed(42)
replicate(10, simfunc())
#             [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7] [,8]   [,9]  [,10]
# cost      200.00 400.00 300.00 300.00 200.00 300.00 300.00  200 400.00 300.00
# totalTime   6.86   6.79   6.95   6.62   6.34   6.81   7.14    6   6.73   6.75
```

(To summarize, store that in a variable and aggregate the row you need. You might find it easier to visualize if you `t`ranspose it to be columnar, and perhaps convert to a `data.frame`, but that's only for your aesthetic benefit, the stats will be the same regardless.)

Also, I'm inferring that you may want `totalTime`, since often simulations like this not only want to know cost over the system's life-cycle, but also the mean-time between fails and some analysis of that. In this case, it appears you've already figured that out (based on your `scale=` and `shape=` parameters), but it can be interesting anyway.

Comment: This is a very helpful and in-depth explanation, thank you!